# Cannot fix Apt corrupted files

Tags: apt, data-corruption

Just after the regular update, I found the apt in a stuck state with corrupted files. Please help me recover.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]   
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources                  
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources [4,808 B]  
Ign:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources              
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Sources [179 kB]  
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages          
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages           
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en          
Hit:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [409 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8,684 B]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Hit:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages [7,512 kB]
Hit:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en      
Hit:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [565 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [547 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [298 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [195 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [488 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [470 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [163 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [208 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,520 B]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,672 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [54.6 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [50.7 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.7 kB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [52.2 kB]
Fetched 11.8 MB in 1min 26s (136 kB/s)                                         

** (appstreamcli:6464): WARNING **: No origin found for file ppa.launchpad.net_stellarium_stellarium-releases_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz

** (appstreamcli:6464): WARNING **: No origin found for file archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz

** (appstreamcli:6464): WARNING **: No origin found for file us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz

** (appstreamcli:6464): WARNING **: No origin found for file us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz

** (appstreamcli:6464): WARNING **: No origin found for file us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

Comment: yes, its a duplicate, solution works. /thanks community.

Answer (score -1):

Sametimes I use `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then `sudo apt-get update` work for me a lot of time!

Try it ;-)

Comment: `autoremove` will remove “orphaned” packages. This may remove packages that OP still needs.